# Jenkin's build failing on npm install

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, jenkins, npm

I'm setting up an ubuntu server that has jenkins for CI.

*When I try to run a build I get failure*

**Question:**
How can I make `npm install` work from my jenkins job?

**build 1:**

```
[morningharwood] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8925730298288495807.sh
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood
+ ls
bower.json
client
e2e
Gruntfile.js
karma.conf.js
package.json
protractor.conf.js
server
+ npm install
/tmp/hudson8925730298288495807.sh: 5: /tmp/hudson8925730298288495807.sh: npm: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkin build
[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
~$ pwd
/home/ubuntu

ls -a


.   .bash_history  .bashrc  .config    .gem    .gnupg  .node-gyp  .nvm      .rbenv  .ssh  .viminfo
..  .bash_logout   .cache   .dotfiles  .gemrc  .local  .npm       .profile  .rvm    .vim
```

Now that I see the `.npm`

```
+ /home/ubuntu/.npm/npm install
/tmp/hudson1456103398115324880.sh: 5: /tmp/hudson1456103398115324880.sh: /home/ubuntu/.npm/npm: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Configuration Script:**

[image]

**What happens when you run from ssh terminal?**

```
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.28: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.11.14","npm":"2.0.0"})
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.11.14
npm ERR! npm  v2.0.0
npm ERR! path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood/node_modules'
...
```

So I've CHOWN the folder:

```
   + pwd
    /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood
   sudo chown ubuntu /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood/ -Rv
   ...
```

Ran npm install after that
       npm install

It was successful!

**NEW PROBLEM:**
My build now fails when trying to clone the repository from github via jenkins.

**Console log**

```
    Started by user matthew harwood
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:matthewharwood/morningharwood.git # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Showing owners:**

```
ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Dec 26 20:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 jenkins jenkins 4096 Dec 26 08:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 ubuntu  jenkins 4096 Dec 26 20:59 morningharwood
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several problems here.

It looks like you are using `node` 0.11.  Why?  Do you need a feature from that unstable branch?

If not, I would recommend using the nodesource packaged `node` modules, as described here: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#usage-instructions

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

This will get you a good installation of `node` and `npm` in the global path, visible to both your `ubuntu` user and the `jenkins` user.

Finally, `/home/ubuntu/.npm/npm` is not an executable, but is the cached version of the `npm` package; `/home/ubuntu/.npm` is the per-user npm download cache.

Comment: Hey man thanks so much for the help! I've burned it down and started again.  I'm recreating the job right now. Will update soon!

Comment: Worked out great!  thanks so much!  hey I have the same problem but with ruby now lol i'm awful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670407/set-up-ruby-globally-for-all-users-on-ubuntu

Comment: "It looks like you are using node 0.11. Why?" what a question. how can someone have a specific reason to use 0,11. do you really expect an answer for that?

Answer (score 3):

As it says:

```
/tmp/hudson8925730298288495807.sh: 5: /tmp/hudson8925730298288495807.sh: npm: not found
```

`npm` isn't available in your path, so change your job to specify full path to `npm`.

For example:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/npm install
```

or wherever `npm` is located.

Comment: Hey I've updated my answer.  I think I have located the proper npm folder but i'm still getting the error.  could you please review?

Comment: could you post the updated configuration and what happens when you execute same command from same user from who jenkins is running

Comment: I've updated the answer.  Also went down another path >_< dunno if it's helpful.

Comment: is your git credentials set up properly ?

Comment: they are when jenkins owns the directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67733/discussion-between-matthew-harwood-and-jigar-joshi).