# Set up ruby globally for all users on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jenkins, permissions

### **Question:**

**How can I install ruby, in such a way, that it's visible to all users on my ubuntu 14.04 server**

ugh I'm trying to make ruby -v visible for all users and I failed.

**Question 2:**
Can I just change permissions? if so, how? if not, how would I uninstall the other installation?

**I have 2 main users:** 
ubuntu (default) and jenkins(secondary)

I followed this set up for rbenv from this [Tut](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10):

```
cd
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.1.5
rbenv global 2.1.5
ruby -v
```

But I did it under the default user

```
+whoami
ubuntu
+ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
```

if i switch users:

```
 +sudo su - jenkins
 +whoami
 jenkins

 +ruby -v
 The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby
 * ruby1.8
 Ask your administrator to install one of them
```

*I'm a super noob when it comes to permissions, so I hope you can hold my hand*

In the end I'm trying to get Jenkins to see ruby for a build.

My Jenkins Job is failing because it cant find sass because it can't find ruby :c

```
4mRunning "test:client" (test) task[24m

[4mRunning "clean:server" (clean) task[24m

[4mRunning "env:all" (env) task[24m

[4mRunning "injector:sass" (injector) task[24m
[90mMissing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead[39m
Injecting [32mscss[39m files [90m(3 files)[39m
[32m>> [39mNothing changed

[4mRunning "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task[24m
    [33mWarning: [4mRunning "sass:server" (sass) task[24m
    [33mWarning: 
    You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
    More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
     Use --force to continue.[39m
```

**UPDATE:**
So I reinstalled rbenv under `sudo su - jenkins` and everything works but is there a way to still install rbenv as a global user or is this not how rbenv is suppose to work??

UPDATE * 2:
My first update didnt work. heres how I did it this time.

```
sudo su -
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
gem install ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your update * 2.

If you want to install something for all users, use

`apt-get install`

`rbenv` is mainly useful if you have to switch between different ruby environments (e.g., you develop multiple apps each need their own, possibly conflicting, set of dependencies installed)

So to answer "Q1  How can I install ruby, in such a way, that it's visible to all users on my ubuntu 14.04 server"

as a privileged user (`root` or possibly `ubuntu`) run

`apt-get install ruby-full`

Questions 2-4: Can I just change permissions? if so, how? if not, how would I uninstall the other installation?

> Can I just change permissions?

This is not just a permissions problem; it's a PATH and permissions problem.  As the jenkins user you can do

`export PATH="~ubuntu/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"`

to add the `ubuntu` user's .rbenv to your path.  But you probably would be better off setting  up `rbenv` for the `jenkins` user.  The jenkins user might not have permissions to read, chdir, and execute the `ubuntu` user's home directory and its .rbenv subdirectory

> How (can I change permissions)

You can change permissions with `chmod`.  But changing permissions can easily screw up your system.  As with wood or paper, it's better to find a way to work *with* the grain of the system (not having to change permissions) rather than *against* the grain of the system.

> How would I uninstall the other installation

`sudo rm -rf ~ubuntu/.rbenv`

You may want to check out a good guide to system administration if you don't have one.  I learned, years ago, from an earlier edition of this book: < http://www.amazon.ca/Essential-System-Administration-Tools-Techniques/dp/0596003439 >