# Can't run npm on ubuntu slave

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, jenkins, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new in jenkins, I want ubuntu 14.04 slave to run nodejs project, I'm using nvm and my nodejs version is 6.3.0, but npm install is failure,

```
[ubuntuElectron] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7587739392227498268.sh
+ npm install
Build step 'exec Shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How to set my node environment variable?I have set npm to

> /usr/local/bin/npm

but it still not working.

Can you help me please ? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661573/jenkins-build-failing-on-npm-install

Answer (score 0):

> https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27170

try this it may help you. i think it may be of path issue....